software indicated in published papers
A lot of papers of numerical simulation specify what software they use in the numerics section. It seems that authors usually indicate software when commercial software is used. What if they don't indicate it and will merely this lead to a bad outcome of the 1st round of review? Under what circumstances must authors indicate what software they use? Whether or not related to commercial, open source or free software?

I think that this question is better suited for Academia.Exchange.

Can you explain what your concern is? Are you asking for one of your own papers?

This is not an unreasonable or trivial question, but it will depend heavily on general practices in your field and the practices of specific journals

You could contact the authors and ask them if they don't indicate it. Some people also just use their own code with no external libraries, so it doesn't make sense indicating it, especially if it's not available. People indicate software as attribution and also for reproducibility purposes.

As a general rule, if credit is due to someone else who wrote a piece of software, then you should cite them!

@WolfgangBangerth no particular concern, but just wonder why authors usually indicate software when commercial software is used and what will happen if they don't

Let me put into an answer what is probably too long for a comment:

In general, you need to explain in a paper what it is you did in as much detail as is necessary for others to reproduce your results. If the software is relevant in this context -- say, you used a specific piece of finite element software -- then it is necessary to state that. On the other hand, if all you did was use a common spreadsheet software's common functionality (which is exchangeable between all major spreadsheet programs), then it is not necessary to state what that was.

At least for open source software, where authors do not benefit financially from the work they put into their software, it is certainly useful to their careers if you cite their work.



thank you! What if they don't indicate the software and will merely this lead to a bad outcome of the 1st round of review?

@feynman It shouldn't as the reviewers have no way of knowing whether you are using your own code or some proprietary package you are paying for. The fact that the reviewers have no way of telling doesn't mean you shouldn't provide proper attribution when using someone else's code. It also matters for reproducibility purposes, and you may be asked by reviewers to make your code available - you are of course not forced to oblige, especially if it is your own code. How important this is depends on the paper and venue. If your paper focuses on code instead of a general concept things differ.

@feynman As mentioned, what happens to your specific paper in this specific round of review is something we cannot know. But you should strive to follow the general guidelines in my answer for future papers.

Another thought: off-the-shelf vs. home-spun
Imagine you write a paper investigating some problem via a computational method, e.g., finite element. If you use your own in-house code, then readers and reviewers might be interested not only in the problem at hand, but also on the implementation itself.
If you're using an off-the-self computational model, i.e., commercial or open-source software, then all the implementation-related questions are automatically covered.

How does the numerical discretisation work? Look into the documentation or the source code.
Is the computational method validated against measurements? Look into the documentation or the source code.
etc.

Stating the software at all, already answers some questions.
I studied X using CFD.
But how?
By using CFD-software Y.
Furthermore, by stating the model selection and parameters of the software, you basically cover a lot of the numerical math that's involved.


Under what circumstances must authors indicate what software they use?

Firstly, there is no 'must.' Authors who publish papers are not obliged to mention the software they used if the reviewers don't complain about it.
Secondly, published papers serve different purposes in the case of authors. Not all papers hold the same value. For instance, say someone had poor grades in the bachelors, and he/she needed a paper to look better in front of the PhD admissions committee, etc.
As an author, it is a part of your academic ethics to supply relevant information so that other researchers can reproduce your results. However, it is not mandatory as long as your paper gets a green signal from your reviewer.

I don't see this answer as useful. What's the point of writing papers for reviewers? A paper that passes peer review because the reviewer does a poor job, but that otherwise is poorly written and does not describe the work adequately is not useful to anyone and does not contribute to the world's knowledge. I don't think we ought to recommend this as the standard.
